# Printing max element in a Deque<Integer>

Tags: java, deque, arraydeque

I have a Deque from Integers, which I'm using as a Que. I have to add and remove elements from it and in some cases I need to print the max value in the Que.

The thing that I've tried is:

```
System.out.println(deque.stream().max(Integer::compareTo));
```

But it prints - `Optional[the current max int]`.

Thank you!

Comment: you can do ``optional.getAsInt()`` to get the actual value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the `max` method of `java.util.Stream` returns your value wrapped in `Optional`. This is the signature of the max method `Optional<T> max(Comparator<? super T> comparator);`

The example below would provide you the expected behaviour:

```
Optional<Integer> optionalOfMax = deque.stream().max(Integer::compareTo);
System.out.println(optionalOfMax.orElseThrow());
```

Comment: Is there any reason we call `orElseThrow()` if `isPresent()` is true? Isn't it violate the purpose of optional?

Comment: True. My initial response got edited by an editor. The initial version did a call to `.get()` instead. But that will get replaced by `orElseThrow()`.. so, the final version should make the call to `.orElseThrow()` without the prior call to `.isPresent()`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it as follows:

```
deque.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Note that `deque.stream().max(Integer::compareTo)` returns `Optional<Integer>`.

Alternatively,

```
deque.stream().flatMapToInt(x -> IntStream.of(x)).max().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

[`Stream#flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-) returns an `IntStream` consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the code you have written and extend it by `.get()`.

The following code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a Deque that holds Integers
    Deque<Integer> myDQ = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    // add some of them
    myDQ.add(12);
    myDQ.add(13);
    myDQ.add(14);
    myDQ.add(15);
    myDQ.add(16);
    myDQ.add(20);
    myDQ.add(17);
    myDQ.add(18);
    myDQ.add(19);
    // and print
    System.out.println(
            myDQ.stream()
                .max(Integer::compareTo) // the largest one
                .get() // not as Optional but only as Integer
    );
}
```

just prints `20`.

Comment: Note that `get()` on `Optional` is supposed to become deprecated. Use `orElseThrow()` instead, which does the same but has a _better_ name.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbox the Integer wrappers in your queue and use [IntStream.max()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max()), which returns an OptionalInt:

```
deque.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .max()
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

This will do nothing if `max()` returns `OptionalInt.empty()`, which happens when the deque is empty. If you want to check for emptiness, you can do, for example:

```
deque.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .max()
    .ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println,
            () -> throw new RuntimeException("Attempt to get max of empty collection"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `max`-Method returns an `java.util.Optional`. If you just want to return a int-Value you can use the `orElse`-Method from `java.util.Optional` to return the given value or, if not present, another default.

```
System.out.println(deque.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).orElse(0));
```